# SQL Server could not display the Schedule dialog box

Tags: sql-server, merge-replication

I'm trying to establish a merge replication between SQL Server 2012 (SP2) servers. In the New Subscription Wizard, I want to setup the Agent Schedule and I have the following error when selecting "Define schedule..."

[image]

Of course I have Googled the error but can't find anything helpfull.

thanks for your time and help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you leave the subscription as `Run on demand only` during creation, then invoke it manually via Replication Monitor to see if it synchronizes your data successfully and then add the synchronization schedule manually via a call to `sp_addmergepushsubscription_agent` like below:

> exec sp_addmergepushsubscription_agent @publication = N'Publication_Name', @subscriber = N'Subscriber_Server_Name', @subscriber_db = N'Subscriber_DB', @job_login = null, @job_password = null, @subscriber_security_mode = 1, @publisher_security_mode = 1, @frequency_type = 4, @frequency_interval = 1, @frequency_relative_interval = 1, @frequency_recurrence_factor = 0, @frequency_subday = 8, @frequency_subday_interval = 1, @active_start_time_of_day = 100, @active_end_time_of_day = 235959, @active_start_date = 0, @active_end_date = 0

The above call will add `run-once-per-hour-every-day` schedule to a merge publication called `Publication_Name` in the subscriber server name `Subscriber_Server_Name` and Subscriber DB = `Subscriber_DB`.

I have obtained this call example by running `Generate Scripts` over my existing Merge Publication with Subscription schedule defined.

Read more about `sp_addmergepushsubscription_agent` parameters and their possible values here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-addmergepushsubscription-agent-transact-sql

Note, this is not uncommon for some Replication related action to fail in SSMS UI but to succeed via manual stored procedure execution. You just need to generate the correct `sp_*` call.

Hope this helps to resolve your issue.

Comment: @Dominic, you're welcome! Thanks for the answer accept and vote-up :).